# Comment on (write once) database design storing network information

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have raw logs of up to a week of associations of wifi enabled devices to the wifi routers in my Institute.
As of now I plan to put it in a database as follows:
One big table having columns:

- Router MAC address
- Device MAC address
- Timestamp

**The database will be queried only to retrieve connection history of a particular device over the week.**
After a record becomes one week old, it will be deleted or moved somewhere else.

Now the number of devices are possibly between 800 to 2000. So it does not make sense to have a separate table for each device, or does it?

The number of wifi routers are about <40 I believe.

Finally, the log of a week will be less than 1 GB.

I am for now using a SQL database(really sticking to this, dont want to change, but please mention an alternative if it has drastic improvement).

**Now my question is that is the (one table) approach efficient time wise - time to for query to get executed and return results.**
Space and redundancy are no problems, just the speed at which the query comes back*.

**Also comment on what possible measures/modifications can be taken to make such a system scalable.**

**It should not be so complicated that it becomes difficult to maintain.*

Comment: I believe in the KISS method - Keep It Simple Sir. I cant think of any reasons off hand that you need to complicate it with multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why you would need to split this up any other way. If your sole purpose is to store Router and Device Addresses with a datetime stamp there really is nothing else you need to do. One table would do it.

The whole idea behind normalization (yes I am over simplifying it here) is that you should never have to repeat the same data over and over again in multiple tables.

For example say you wanted to store this:

```
Router | Mac Address | Device Type | IP Address | Device Model | Device Serial Number
```

It would be better to have a router/device table that specifies all this and has a specific `DeviceID` and one that has say

```
DeviceID | TimeStamp
```

You would do this so you wouldnt have to repeat all the information every time for each log entry.

Hope this helps...

Comment: But as the table size increases wont the lookup using DeviceID | Timestamp become slower? Any way around that?

Comment: Are you considering this option of creating multiple tables. I think you should really just go with the simple 1 table setup.

Comment: 2000 devices X 40 routers =  80,000 rows X 7 days in a week is only 560,000 rows. SQL is still yawning at that level.... if you were keeping the records and you were growing by .5M per week... that could get big fast and you might have to look at some indexing. IMHO Keep it Simple Sir...

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way you are storing and removing the data, my suggestion would be to create a single table, partitioned by timestamp. The benefits of this method:

- Archiving data (dropping partition, moving partition) has less of a penalty than large DELETEs.
- The table size that you are querying will be smaller, thus queries should be faster (caveats always apply).
- If you partition by timestamp and use that partitioning key in your queries, constraint exclusion will come into play, meaning that on the partitions that contain the data you are after will be queried, and the others will be discarded from the plan.

On top of that, you can index over multiple columns with indexes designed specifically to quickly retrieve data for your queries. What those indexes will look like is impossible to say at this time as there is no DDL, sample data, or queries (that can be a follow up question).
Using a CLUSTERed index could help too, as you have static data (WORM).

If you need really fast lookups on the INET types (if the built-in network datatypes are not fast enough that is), they have a look at the IP4R data type: http://pgfoundry.org/projects/ip4r/

Comment: Thanks for pointing to partitioning. Didn't know of it before. Might use in version 2.

Comment: Partitioning's biggest benefit isn't necessarily performance, it is for maintenance of data, aka dropping partitions etc.